# Would variables that don't differ between the two categories improve classification?

Tags: machine-learning, classification

I want to build do classification to determines if a user will visit another page on the website before logging out. So it's making a binary prediction: last page or not last page.

Would variables that are constant between pages (e.g. user age, user gender) add any value to the model or no?

I mean, I suppose age and gender may be somewhat correlated with the typical number of pages a user visits, but we would already include mean number of page a user visits as a feature.

Would the answer to the question depend on the type of classification algorithm used?

Comment: Suppose you're on a site where old people stay for hours and hours, but young people leave right away. (Maybe it follows step function at age 18.) Obviously, age affects your predictions. Am I mis-understanding your question?

Comment: Do you include individual fixed effects?

Comment: To clarify, for each user we want to make a prediction. Each user visits, say 5 pages on average (and maybe it does change by age or gender). As they go through each page, we want to predict: is this the last page?

Answer (score 1):

The answer to this question hinges on whether you already include individual fixed effects.

#### An interpretation of your question:

**Q**: If I already have individual fixed effects in my model, can I increase prediction power by adding right hand side variables (eg. gender) that don't vary within an individual?

**A**: In the context of classic linear models (eg. linear regression), the answer is **no**. All it would do is change your estimate of the fixed effects and none of your predictions would change at all.

If you ran the following two regressions:
$$y_{it} = \hat{a} + \hat{b}_1 x_{it} + \hat{u}_i +\hat{\epsilon}_{it}$$
$$y_{it} = a + b_1 x_{it} + b_2 z_i + u_i + \epsilon_{it}$$

Your forecasting power would be the same, and you'd have $\hat{u}_i = b_2 z_i + u_i$.

**Q**: Moving beyond ordinary least squares regression, could it change things?

**A**: Yes. In the most general sense, you need not have the equivalence. I would not expect it to improve things (since the data is collinear), but perhaps in certain contexts it could? Eg. repeating the same feature in a random forest could give it a higher probability of being selected etc...

Answer (score 0):

Your question may be wrongly worded, as the age or gender of a person does not really stay the same between the two categories, which are whether the user will visit another page or not.
This is because for a given user, they cannot be in both categories at the same time.

But whether there is any correlation between certain features and the propensity of a user to stay on that page or not, needs to be found from the data. You would ideally like to consider a large pool of possible features and then perform [feature selection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feature_selection) to prune out the ones that do not seem to be correlated.

Comment: I think I wasn't very clear. So a user will go on the website and visit for instance 5 pages. Each page they visit, we want to predict whether it's their last page.
So, for pages 1-4, the answer is no. For page 5, the answer is yes. Demographics data for that individual user will remain the same between pages 1-4 and 5.